# Verb meaning the same as "to be late" or "to become late"

Tags: verbs, synonyms

In other languages that I know there are verbs which describe the action of becoming late. They are more commonly used than adjective form that is used in English.

"To be late". Here "late" is adjective describing the state of someone.

Is there a verb meaning the same thing, (something in the form of "I lated to the class")?

Comment: there is the somewhat dated term "dallied" .  It's been picking up more humorous meanings over time...it suggests more of a trivial use of time making you late generally.

Comment: There is also _dawdle_  which means to "Waste time; be slow."  But that doesn't necessarily imply _to become late_.  My kids tend to dawdle in the morning when getting ready for school, but getting there 20 minutes before the bell is only late in my wife's eyes.

Comment: There is no common verb used for this. (As answerers and commenters suggest, there are more precise verbs that can describe the way in which you became late.)

Comment: English doesn’t have all that many verbs that encapsulate *be* predicates: to be late, to be angry, to be young, to be jealous, to be in luck, to be in season, to be balding, to be mistaken, to be quick, to be dead. Some you can find decent verbs for, but not many and not often.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for something shorter than "be late", you may be out of luck. But it is of course possible to ***run behind schedule***

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20behind%20schedule):

> to arrive and/or leave later than the time that is expected

Comment: *Run* does not mean to be late.

Answer (score 1):

"Tardy" apparently has an [obsolete verb-form](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tardy#Verb). But I don't know of a contemporary word that has replaced it.

Comment: "to tardy" required a direct object and it meant ***To make tardy; to delay, retard, keep back*** (OED).

Comment: "I tardied myself."

Comment: Evan is right, I don't know where the downvote comes from. It clearly says on the wiktionary page that tardy is also a verb, although nearly never used, because it's obsolete.

Comment: The Polish verb (się spóźnić) is also reflexive, so I'll buy _tardy oneself_ for English, obsolete or not. But  Evan should put that reflexivity in the answer, because that makes it address the question.

Comment: @Spencer I'm not here to mess around with grammar.

Answer (score 1):

***Delay*** might work, as in "*I delayed going to the class*" or "*I was delayed in getting to the class.*"

> ***[Delay](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/delay)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Make (someone or something) late or slow.
>      *‘the train was delayed’*
>
>    1.1 no object Be late or slow; loiter.
>       *‘time being of the essence, they delayed no longer’*
>
>    1.2 Postpone or defer (an action)
>       *‘he may decide to delay the next cut in interest rates’*

Answer (score 1):

**to be tardy**

> 1. late, overdue, unpunctual, belated, dilatory, behindhand *He was as tardy as ever for our appointment*.

*([Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tardy))*

Examples:

> I was tardy to the class
>
> I was tardy to school

Comment: That does not answer the question. The only verb there is *be*; *tardy* is no more part of the verb than *late* is.

Comment: @tchrist - I checked to make sure OP hadn't asked for a single word.

Comment: Y veo que tardaste bastante en hacerlo. That's the kind of verb we need here. ;-)

Comment: @tchrist - Well, I guess there's always *tarry*.